# using kendo-ui datasource data with multiple dropdown widgets

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I want to use  Datasource data with multiple dropdowns, if I use shared dataSource that makes ajax requests as much as the number of the dropdowns  to server. what I need is  1 ajax request and use that data to populate all dropdowns.
this code gives me  ildata is not defined..

thanks for help.

code example

```
var ilDataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read:  {
      url: "{{ url('ajax/ilList') }}",
      dataType: "json" 
    }
  }
});
ilDataSource.fetch(function(){
  var ildata = ilDataSource.data();
});

var iller = $("#iller").kendoDropDownList({
  placeholder: "İl Seçiniz",
  dataSource : {
    data:  ildata
  },
  dataTextField: "il",
  dataValueField: "id"
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

I can get data items in function scope but cant get in common scope..

```
   ilDataSource.fetch(function() { 
   ildata = ilDataSource.data().toJSON();
   console.log(ildata); });
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ilDataSource.fetch(function(){
>   var ildata = ilDataSource.data();
> });
> ```

This defines a *local* variable `ildata` scoped to the anonymous function.

> ```
> dataSource : {
>   data:  ildata
> },
> ```

thus at this point there is no variable/property `ildata`.

You need to declare `ildata` at a common scope for the two use cases:

```
var ildata;
ilDataSource.fetch(function(){
  ildata = ilDataSource.data();
});

var iller = $("#iller").kendoDropDownList({
  placeholder: "İl Seçiniz",
  dataSource : {
    data:  ildata
  },
  dataTextField: "il",
  dataValueField: "id"
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Whether Kendo can handle this re-use of a single DataSource is another question.

Comment: ilDataSource.fetch(function()

        {
            ildata = ilDataSource.data().toJSON();
            console.log(ildata);
        });

I can see data items in console.how can I get out of fetch function?

Comment: @EfeEngin Put that into a new question (and code is basically impossible to read in comments).

Comment: @EfeEngin So that's some code, but what's wrong with it? When you step through with the debugger is the value of `ildata` data changed? Have you considered that the `fetch` event will occur after you initialise the drop down: you need to refresh the drop down to pick up the data.

Comment: after  init of  datasource and fetch function when I console.log I get  undefined. yes when in fetch function I can get data  in other scopes I get undefined.

Comment: @EfeEngin Please rewrite in English being explicit about what you are referencing: "when I console.log I get undefined" is meaningless

Comment: when I log the variable into the console of chrome.  if I am in scope of function fetch, I see data items object. otherwise undefined.

Comment: @EfeEngin Please re-read the third sentence of my second comment. The fetch is called later than the drop down list is initialised. You need to force `$("#iller")` to re-load.